# ibm business card integration for xpages using OpenNTF project Business Card

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

Using http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Business%20Card I can implement this no problem when it is rendered in a static context, for example, hard coded with display name and username.

The problem:

When using this custom control within a repeat control where the repeat is populated from an xml feed. Using XPath we can get the email and display name.

The xpage will render the list with the url based on the display name. However it takes a page refresh for the javascript to rebuild the link to actually do the tiptext and the popup.

Has anybody implemented this in a dynamic context eg a search bar for people in connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This project is very old. Take a look at the business card control (Java/lib control) in XPagesSBT.nsf in the extlib project (exlibx package).

Comment: I've tried that, but I get
 ReferenceError: SemTagSvc is not defined
[Break On This Error]  
...jo.addOnLoad(dojo.hitch(this,function(){ SemTagSvc.parseDom(null, this.id, 0 );}...

I think this uses the same code thou as the wiki http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Integrating_the_Profiles_business_card_ic40&content=pdcontent so I would expect the same issue of rendering in a dynamic context.

Comment: I remember having seen this error. I think it was related to a defect in an older Connections version (3.0?).

Comment: We are on connections 4CR2... The problem is that the page needs to have the content on before the javascript function runs, however I haven't found a way to successfully do this in XPages.